# Ordered list in c++

Tags: c++, list, linked-list

I'm trying to create an ordered list in C++, but it doesn't recognize the node struct type in the insert function. Sorry for naming non in english some variables like testa and inserimento that are head and input.

LISTA.CPP

```
    #include <iostream>
    #include "Lista.h"
    #include <stddef.h>

using namespace std;

void insert(){
    Lista l;
    inserimento->next = NULL;
    cout<<"inserisci elemento"<<"\n";
    cin>>inserimento->num;
    if(testa==NULL){
        inserimento->next=NULL;
        testa=inserimento;
    }
    else
    {
        if(testa->num > inserimento->num) //insert on head
        {
            inserimento->next = testa;
            testa = inserimento;
        }
        else
        {
            temp = testa;
            while(temp->next != NULL && temp->next->num < inserimento->num)
                temp = temp->next;
            if(temp->next == NULL) //insert on least
            {
                temp->next = inserimento;
            }
            else //insert between
            {
                inserimento->next = temp->next;
                temp->next = inserimento;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

LISTA.H

```
 #ifndef LISTA_H_
    #define LISTA_H_
    #include <stddef.h>
    namespace std{
    class Lista {
    public:
        struct nodo{
            struct node *next ;
            int num ;
        };
        nodo *temp = NULL;
        nodo *testa = NULL;
        nodo *inserimento = NULL;
            void insert(nodo);
        };
    }
    #endif /* LISTA_H_ */
```

Thanks in advance

Comment: Indent your code properly if you want other people to read it. And describe the problem in more detail.

Comment: `Lista::nodo::next` is of type `node` - looks like a typo, shouldn't it be `nodo` as well?

Answer (score 0):

1. Do not add any classes or methods to the `std` namespace. It's not for you.
2. Typically, the insert() method, when implementing a list of objects, takes a pointer to the list class's instance, and not a list class's instance.
3. Your implemention of insert() is implementing a function named insert, and not a method of the `Lista` class, a.k.a `Lista::insert()`.

Comment: Thanks you but can you explain me the 2nd point? Sorry for the noob but I'm a student not a professionist.